# How to detect and combine elements in a vector in R?

Tags: r, sum, element

I have a data list including many elements of which I only need the columns 'interval..s' (bout duration) and 'ActivityCode'(0 to 5), see picture ([datalist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCOPz.jpg)).
I try to extract all 0 and 5 in the column 'ActivityCode' with their corresponding value from the column 'interval..s'.
I already wrote a code to extract the bout durations (from column 'interval..s') with an activity code 0 and 5, but bout durations should be summed when 0 and 5 are two consecutive bouts

```
setwd("/Users/lucp9693/Desktop/csvfolder")
mydir = "csvfolder"
myfiles = list.files(path = mydir, pattern = ".csv",full.names = TRUE)
setwd("/Users/lucp9693/Desktop/csvfolder")
list.files(pattern = ".csv$")
list.filenames = list.files(pattern = ".csv$")
list.data = list()
ind = 0
result = vector("numeric",length(list.filenames))
for(i in 1:length(list.filenames))
{
  ind = ind +1
  list.data[[i]] = read.csv(list.filenames[i])
  document = read.csv(list.filenames[i],header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  W = document$Interval..s.[bestand$ActivityCode..0.sedentary.1.standing.2.stepping.2.1.cycling.3.1.primary.lying..3.2.secondary.lying.4.non.wear.5.travelling.==0]
```

It there any possibility to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my reading of your question (with some sample data):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

data <- tibble(
  Interval = round(runif(n = 100, min = 1, max = 1000), 1),
  ActivityCode = round(runif(n = 100, min = 0, max = 5),0)
)

data <- data %>%
  filter(ActivityCode == 0 | ActivityCode == 5) %>%
  mutate(sum = ifelse(ActivityCode == lag(ActivityCode, 1),Interval + lag(Interval, 1), Interval))
```

I remove all lines except those with an ActivityCode of 0 and 5. If there are adjacent or consecutive occurrences of either 0 or 5 the two adjacent Intervals are summed. 
With this output:

```
> print.data.frame(data)
   Interval ActivityCode    sum
1      87.1            0     NA
2      38.7            0  125.8
3     843.1            5  843.1
4     680.6            5 1523.7
5     151.3            5  831.9
6      37.8            0   37.8
7     539.6            0  577.4
8     978.6            5  978.6
9     140.0            5 1118.6
10    145.1            5  285.1
11    252.5            0  252.5
12     90.0            0  342.5
13    588.8            5  588.8
14    459.1            0  459.1
```

Was this what you were after?